# Pull Engine Yard DB into Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line, heroku, engineyard

I want to transfer my application over from Engine Yard to Heroku. The problem is that I don't know how to get my database from one to the other. I know that you can probably do this with the command line but I don't know how. I'm hoping that someone else has one this and would be willing to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get your database from EY to a DB running on your machine - what DB are you using on EY? MySQL perhaps? It should be easy enough to get this done - once you have it locally and have configured your local app to use that database as it's development datasource it's a simple case of `heroku db:push` to put it onto Heroku - and it will convert it on the way up for you so it doesn't entirely matter what DB you run it in locally.

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.